# Можно ли употреблять слово «раньше», когда ожидаемо было «менее чем минута»?

Tags: лингвистика

«Господа, я полагаю, ревизор появится здесь менее чем за минуту. 
Но ревизор появился ещё раньше».

Правильно ли употреблять слово «раньше», когда ожидаемо было «менее чем минута»? Что может быть раньше, чем менее минуты?

Comment: что именно заставляет вас думать, что "раньше" можно употреблять только описывая события, произошедшие больше, чем минуту назад?

Answer (score 4):

Мне кажется, в контексте *появления* выражение ***"менее, чем ЗА минуту"*** нелогично, хоть и звучит гладко. Оно логично, когда речь идёт о продолжительном действии, например

> Робот, умеющий складывать одежду менее, чем за минуту

так как ***за*** означает ***в течение***. А *появление* для стороннего наблюдателя всегда одномоментно, у него нет продолжительности во времени.

В контексте *появления* логично выражение ***"менее, чем ЧЕРЕЗ минуту"***

К слову, в украинском предлог ***за*** означает в том числе ***через*** (в аспекте времени)

Answer (score 4):

Выражение неудачно, поскольку формально приходится отнести "ещё раньше" **к названной оценке** "менее минуты" (от нуля до минуты), а **не к ожиданиям** говорящего. Он мог подразумевать, в дополнение к названной им оценке, примерное количество времени, но никак свои ожидания *не обозначил* и не уточнил перед количественным сравнением. Поэтому "ещё раньше" здесь приходится трактовать как "*он уже здесь*", "*добрался за несколько секунд*" (мне о секундах надо было думать, а не о минутах) и т. п.

Неудачно употребление предлога "**за**" (по смыслу здесь нужно "через"). Как уже отмечено, "появляются" люди единомоментно, а предлог может говорить либо о *затраченном* времени (добраться **за** такое-то время), либо об интервале времени ранее какого-то момента (напр. **за столько-то времени до** начала мероприятия).

Со временами расхождение: полаг*аю*, появится -> появился.

Answer (score 1):

Не усматриваю никаких проблем.

Любое количество секунд, меньшее 60, будет меньше минуты. Обозначим его `N`. Это - ожидаемое/оценочное время, упомянутое в цитате в виде *"менее чем за минуту"*.
Любое количество секунд, меньшее `N`, будет соответствовать *"раньше"*.

Answer (score 1):

> «Господа, я полагаю, ревизор появится здесь менее чем за минуту. Но ревизор появился ещё раньше».

1. Должно быть "я полагАЛ" - в прошедшем времени. Поскольку ревизор уже "появился", то вы сейчас уже больше ничего не полагаете. Вы закончили полагать в момент "ревизор появился", а это было в прошлом.
2. Как упоминалось, "менее, чем ЧЕРЕЗ минуту"
3. Что может быть раньше, чем менее минуты? - да что угодно. Половина минуты, например. Чтобы проплыть под парусом вокруг света - нужны недели, или даже месяцы. Чтобы взорвать реактор Чернобыльской АЭС хватило 4 с половиной секунд. Считать, что минута - это оооочень мало, и что делить её нельзя, не стоит. Это очень зависит от контекста. Если например до закрытия офиса оставалось 50 секунд и вы надеялись, что он не успеет и прибежит после закрытия, а он успел за 40 секунд, то не будет ничего странного в меньших чем минута отрезках времени.
4. Правильно ли употреблять слово «раньше»? - да. Но можно использовать и другие слова. Зависит от того, с чем "сравнивается", к какой части предыдущей фразы отсылает это слово.

   - Но ревизор появился ещё раньше [[, чем я полагал]].
   - Но ревизор появился ещё быстрее [[, чем прошлa та минута]].

Оба варианта вполне нормальны.